# How can I make my android app connect to the internet? (Unity)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, web

I'm doing an Android application that request info from a website (I already made the website) and displays it on the screen.

I have this code to do that:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WebTextLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    [Serializable]
    public class PlaceInfo
    {
        public string Titulo = "";
        public string Texto = "";
    }

    public string URL;
    public Text TituloUI;
    public Text TextoUI;

    public PlaceInfo placeInfo;



    public void Start()
    {
        if (Debug.isDebugBuild)
        {
            StartCoroutine(GetRequest(URL));

        }
    }
    IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
        {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

            string jsonForm = uri;

            if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log("Error loading");

            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    placeInfo = JsonUtility.FromJson<PlaceInfo>(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                    TituloUI.text = placeInfo.Titulo;
                    TextoUI.text = placeInfo.Texto;

                }
                catch
                {
                    Debug.Log("Error in connection");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And this is how the component looks:

[picture of the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoQiJ.png)

(I already tried changing htttp to https)

Now, when I test it on the Unity editor, it works perfectly, but when I try it on my phone, it doesn't. The text never loads.

I thought it was something about the permissions, so I gave the internet and the access_network_state, still didn't work (I also have the internet on require in the player settings)

I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform network operations in your application, your manifest must include the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: I think you forgot to write the permissions

Comment: LOL, they were saved as links, I've updated the answer.